# Interactive Brokers: Is Flex Web Service with Paper Account possible?

Tags: interactive-brokers

I am testing an automated system each day and I want to pull daily trade reports.  The Flex Query is perfect, and works with my Live Account, but I cannot figure out how to make it work with the Paper Account.  I can create a Flex Query in the Paper Account, but I don't see a way to setup a token to use the Flex Web Service in the paper account.  Is it possible?

If not, any suggestions on how I can get an a daily trade log of my actual trades/executions?

Comment: Have you tried asking IB's tech support https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1560 ?

Comment: Yeah, and they seem pretty clueless.  I think the people on here are smarter than the tech support at IB.

Comment: The ones writing their blog https://www.tradersinsight.news/category/ibkr-quant-news/ sound mostly clueful :)

Answer (score 1):

I also addressed this issue in forums and with the support. Outcome: Flex reports are not available for paper accounts.